# OMXPlayer Stops Looping

Tags: omxplayer, media

I am using the following command to loop a video with omxplayer:

`sudo omxplayer --no-keys --no-osd -o both --loop --aspect-mode fill '/root/video.mp4' &`

However after between 22-24 hours the playback just stops. I added `-g` for logging but the log file is about 2GB by the time it quits. Here are the last 20 lines of the file:

```
00:47:26 T:18446744072196392260   DEBUG: Normal M:376507546 (A:376874667 V:376840000) P:0 A:0.37 V:0.33/T:0.20 (0,0,1,1) A:0% V:0% (0.20,6.07)
00:47:26 T:18446744072196412552   DEBUG: Normal M:376527995 (A:376874667 V:376840000) P:0 A:0.35 V:0.31/T:0.20 (0,0,1,1) A:0% V:0% (0.18,6.07)
00:47:26 T:18446744072196432826   DEBUG: Normal M:376548269 (A:376874667 V:376840000) P:0 A:0.33 V:0.29/T:0.20 (0,0,1,1) A:0% V:0% (0.16,6.07)
00:47:26 T:18446744072196453121   DEBUG: Normal M:376568564 (A:376874667 V:376840000) P:0 A:0.31 V:0.27/T:0.20 (0,0,1,1) A:0% V:0% (0.14,6.07)
00:47:26 T:18446744072196473396   DEBUG: Normal M:376588839 (A:376874667 V:376840000) P:0 A:0.29 V:0.25/T:0.20 (0,0,1,1) A:0% V:0% (0.12,6.07)
00:47:26 T:18446744072196493821   DEBUG: Normal M:376609110 (A:376874667 V:376840000) P:0 A:0.27 V:0.23/T:0.20 (0,0,1,1) A:0% V:0% (0.09,6.07)
00:47:26 T:18446744072196514093   DEBUG: Normal M:376629534 (A:376874667 V:376840000) P:0 A:0.25 V:0.21/T:0.20 (0,0,1,1) A:0% V:0% (0.07,6.07)
00:47:26 T:18446744072196534364   DEBUG: Normal M:376649804 (A:376874667 V:376840000) P:0 A:0.22 V:0.19/T:0.20 (0,0,1,0) A:0% V:0% (0.05,6.07)
00:47:26 T:18446744072196534464    INFO: COMXVideo::IsEOS
00:47:26 T:18446744072196555010   DEBUG: Normal M:376670450 (A:376874667 V:376840000) P:0 A:0.20 V:0.17/T:0.20 (0,0,1,0) A:0% V:0% (0.03,6.07)
00:47:26 T:18446744072196575553   DEBUG: Normal M:376690994 (A:376874667 V:376840000) P:0 A:0.18 V:0.15/T:0.20 (0,0,0,0) A:0% V:0% (0.01,6.07)
00:47:26 T:18446744072196596239   DEBUG: Normal M:376711530 (A:376874667 V:376840000) P:0 A:0.16 V:0.13/T:0.20 (0,0,0,0) A:0% V:0% (-0.01,6.07)
00:47:26 T:18446744072196616779   DEBUG: Normal M:376732211 (A:376874667 V:376840000) P:0 A:0.14 V:0.11/T:0.20 (0,0,0,0) A:0% V:0% (-0.03,6.07)
00:47:26 T:18446744072196637776   DEBUG: Normal M:376753207 (A:376874667 V:376840000) P:0 A:0.12 V:0.09/T:0.20 (0,1,0,0) A:0% V:0% (-0.05,6.07)
00:47:26 T:18446744072196658344   DEBUG: Normal M:376773775 (A:376874667 V:376840000) P:0 A:0.10 V:0.07/T:0.20 (0,1,0,0) A:0% V:0% (-0.07,6.07)
00:47:26 T:18446744072196678893   DEBUG: Normal M:376794324 (A:376874667 V:376840000) P:0 A:0.08 V:0.05/T:0.20 (1,1,0,0) A:0% V:0% (-0.09,6.07)
00:47:26 T:18446744072196699587   DEBUG: Normal M:376814878 (A:376874667 V:376840000) P:0 A:0.06 V:0.03/T:0.20 (1,1,0,0) A:0% V:0% (-0.11,6.07)
00:47:26 T:18446744072196720138   DEBUG: Normal M:376835569 (A:376874667 V:376840000) P:0 A:0.04 V:0.00/T:0.20 (1,1,0,0) A:0% V:0% (-0.13,6.07)
00:47:26 T:18446744072196720376    INFO: COMXAudio::IsEOS
00:47:26 T:18446744072196720524   DEBUG: OMXReader::SeekTime(0) - seek ended up on time -2147483648
```

Is this normal or am I missing something? I want the video to play looped forever or until the user intervenes. The video folder I am using is mounted via a samba share, this is still connected after the video stops playing though.

P.S - RPi3 with latest buster image installed.

Comment: This is obviously not normal. Maybe you should file a bug to the developers.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Will do, thanks!